# Inject JavaScript code from asp.net page into html page in another domain

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

How can I inject a JavaScript code from asp.net page into html page in another domain e.g http://www.codeproject.com/ . how to inject a JavaScript into this html page from my application

I am currently working on making a plugin just like Pinterest when the html page opens from my application it shows a bookmarklet just like Pinterest automatically on the page.

Below is the code I am using to inject JavaScript

```
public partial class ViewPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
           string script = "javascript:(function(){var jsdom = document.createElement('script');jsdom.src = 'http://localhost:15064/Script/delete.js';document.body.appendChild(jsdom);})();";
           Response.Redirect(Server.UrlEncode(script));
    }
}
```

Below is the Error I get After the execution of above code

[image]

Comment: You can't do that, that's a security breach (imagine script being "redirect to a bank site and transfer all the money to me")

Comment: http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html

Answer (score 0):

Same Original Policy will not allow you to run scripts in someone else's domain.If this did not exist anyone could run scripts in any domain which would be a major security risk.

There are a couple *legal exceptions to this rule which you can read below

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

The only other way to accomplish outside of an agreement with both sides would be a violation of Same Origin and probably illegal.

Xss attacks are pretty common and do what you are describing.

Answer (score 0):

The closest you will probably be able to get is a bookmarklet:

http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/javascript-bookmarklet-basics/

which is basically a shortcut to inline javascript.

An example in the wild is the X-Ray Goggles bookmarklet. You can add it by creating a new bookmark and pasting the location as:

```
javascript:(function(){var script=document.createElement('script');script.src='https://goggles.webmaker.org/en-US/webxray.js';script.className='webxray';script.setAttribute('data-lang','en-US');script.setAttribute('data-baseuri','https://goggles.webmaker.org/en-US');document.body.appendChild(script);})();
```

This won't let you inject from your application but it is a way of injecting into a doc from your browser.